# Why am I not getting a segmentation fault with this code? (Bus error)

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault

I had a bug in my code that went like this.

```
char desc[25];
char name[20];
char address[20];
sprintf (desc, "%s %s", name, address);
```

Ideally this should give a segfault. However, I saw this give a bus error. 
Wikipedia says something to the order of 'Bus error is when the program tries to access an unaligned memory location or when you try to access a physical (not virtual) memory location that does not exist or is not allowed. '

The second part of the above statement sounds similar to a seg fault. So my question is, when do you get a SIGBUS and when a SIGSEGV?

EDIT:- 
Quite a few people have mentioned the context. I'm not sure what context would be needed but this was a buffer overflow lying inside a static class function that get's called from a number of other class functions. If there's something more specific that I can give which will help, do ask.

Anyways, someone had commented that I should simply write better code. I guess the point of asking this question was "can an application developer infer anything from a SIGBUS versus a SIGSEGV?" (picked from that blog post below)

Comment: Just to clarify, this guy is looking for the difference between a SIGBUS and SIGSEGV, not the reason why the posted code generates one or the other.

Comment: @Pochi, I think cnicutar's answer still applies. Once you hit undefined or illegal behaviour virtually anything can happen. It depends on the OS/hardware. We don't even know if the error happens on the `sprintf` line, perhaps it just corrupts memory and something else generates the actual error.

Comment: Nice blog-https://blogs.oracle.com/peteh/entry/sigbus_versus_sigsegv_according_to

Comment: @Pochi Well I was hoping to get answers to both questions.

Comment: Unknowable give the context information provided.

Comment: How is this is a C++ question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you probably realize, the base cause is undefined behavior in your
program.  In this case, it leads to an error detected by the hardware,
which is caught by the OS and mapped to a signal.  The exact mapping 
isn't really specified (and I've seen integral division by zero result
in a `SIGFPE`), but generally: `SIGSEGV` occurs when you access out of
bounds, `SIGBUS` for other accessing errors, and `SIGILL` for an illegal
instruction.  In this case, the most likely explination is that your
bounds error has overwritten the return address on the stack.  If the
return address isn't correctly aligned, you'll probably get a `SIGBUS`,
and if it is, you'll start executing whatever is there, which could
result in a `SIGILL`.  (But the possibility of executing random bytes as
code is what the standards committee had in mind when they defined
“undefined behavior”.  Especially on machines with no memory
protection, where you could end up jumping directly into the OS.)

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate this in a test program but it seems like the most logical explanation. Mike Seymour's answer below also seems to say the same thing. 
So would you say it's possible to create such a small test program or it's pretty pointless?

Comment: @owagh I'd say that it was pretty pointless, although I don't think it would be hard to do for a specific architecture, if you knew exactly how the compiler laid out variables, the stack frame, etc.  This is actually the basis of buffer overrun attacks: if you know some system code has this problem, you send it data to fill the buffer with some nefarious machine code, and to set the return address to point into the buffer.

Answer (score 4):

A segmentation fault is never guaranteed when you're doing fishy stuff with memory. It all depends on a lot of factors (how the compiler lays out the program in memory, optimizations etc).

What may be illegal for a C++ program may not be illegal for a program in general. For instance the OS doesn't care if you step outside an array. It doesn't even know what an array is. However it *does* care if you touch memory that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: So does that mean that it's completely unpredictable? To be more precise, would it be possible to write a program that will always give a SIGBUS even though it is just illegal (but aligned) memory access (something that we usually associate with SIGSEGV)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sensible advice indeed :-)

Answer (score 2):

A segmentation fault occurs if you try to do a data access a *virtual* address that is not mapped to your process. On most operating systems, memory is mapped in pages of a few kilobytes; this means that you often won't get a fault if you write off the end of an array, since there is other valid data following it in the memory page.

A bus error indicates a more low-level error; a wrongly-aligned access or a missing *physical* address are two reasons, as you say. However, the first is not happening here, since you're dealing with bytes, which have no alignment restriction; and I think the second can only happen on data accesses when memory is completely exhausted, which probably isn't happening.

However, I think you might also get a bus error if you try to execute code from an invalid virtual address. This could well be what is happening here - by writing off the end of a *local* array, you will overwrite important parts of the stack frame, such as the function's return address. This will cause the function to return to an invalid address, which (I think) will give a bus error. That's my best guess at what particular flavour of undefined behaviour you are experiencing here.

In general, you can't rely on segmentation faults to catch buffer overruns; the best tool I know of is [valgrind](https://valgrind.org), although that will still fail to catch some kinds of overrun. The best way to avoid overruns when working with strings is to use `std::string`, rather than pretending that you're writing C.

Comment: He doesn't say much about the context, but it looks like he's got buffer overrun on a local variable.  So he could easily modify the return address (or `sprintf` could modify its return address); a misaglined return address will cause `SIGBUS` on a Sparc.  (I've not tried it on an Intel.)  And returning to what is basically a random address can cause just about anything.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed; that's more or less what my third paragraph says.

Comment: So it is.  It's been a long day.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you don't know what kind of garbage you have in the format string. That garbage could potentially result in treating the remaining arguments as those of an "aligned" data type (e.g. `int` or `double`). Treating an unaligned area as an aligned argument definitely causes `SIGBUS` on some systems.

Comment: Frankly I'm not sure I remember what the exact statement was. 
Are you saying that sprintf (desc, "%s %d", name, somechar) where somechar is an unaligned char[4] will give a SIGBUS all the time?
Note that I didn't get a compile time error for the above code...

Answer (score 0):

Given that your string is made up of two other strings each being a max of 20 characters long, yet you are putting it into a field that is 25 characters, that is where your first issue lies.  You are have a good potential to overstep your bounds.

The variable `desc` should be at least 41 characters long (20 + 20 + 1 [for the space you insert]).

Use `valgrind` or `gdb` to figure out why you are getting a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
char desc[25];
char name[20];
char address[20];
sprintf (desc, "%s %s", name, address);
```

Just by looking at this code, I can assume that `name` and `address` each can be `20` chars long. If that is so, then does it not imply that `desc` should be minimum `20+20+1` chars long? (`1` char for the space between `name` and `address`, as specified in the  `sprintf`).

That can be the one reason of segfault. There could be other reasons as well. For example, what if `name` is longer than `20` chars?

So better you use `std::string`:

```
std::string name;
std::string address;
std::string desc = name + " " + address;
char const *char_desc = desc.str(); //if at all you need this
```

Comment: You missed the extra null-character automatically append at the end: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf. So desc size must be 20+1+20+1 ;). To avoid this I would prefer use snprintf but the question is not why there's a segfault but why bus error occurred instead of segfault.